# My sidebar pushes my whole website down

Tags: html, css, sidebar, margins

So I got this website where everything were lined up perfectly, the header, body footer etc. Past week I tried to add a sidebar and I realized that it pushed my main content down. 
So many question is, how can I make the margins/height of my sidebar independent of my main content? (Posted CSS code below)

DEMO:
Edit: http://oldtimesdaily.tumblr.com/
my tumblr with code. How it looks right now. The absolute position worked, the main content is back at top. But now all contents of my sidebar are jammed together, I guess absolute positionen removes all margins? What should I use instead to position the different contents on my sidebar?

```
#quote { /*style for quote division*/
    position:relative;
    width:375px;
    height:70px;
    border:1px solid black;
    font-family:sans-serif;
    font-size:95%;
    padding:3px;
    background-color:lightyellow;
}
#auth { /*style for quote author, if any*/
    position:absolute;
    bottom:3px;
    right:10px;
}
#sidebar {           /*editable*/
    background: url('http://s10.postimg.org/uag5u79d1/vline.png') repeat-y left center;
    background-color: white;
    width: 260px;
    position: relative;
    top: 700px;
    left: 55%;
}
#sidebar .sTitle {
    padding: 0 0 10px 0;
    position: relative;
    margin: 0px 20px 0px;
    color: #222;
    font-size: 15px;
    line-height: 1;
    font-family: QuicksandBold, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-weight: bold;
    letter-spacing: 3px;
    text-decoration: none;
    border-bottom: 0px;
}
#sidebar .Categories {
    font-size: 11px;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 3px 5px;
    margin: 50px;
}
```

Comment: Could you add a link to a demo? use jsfiddle.net or codepen.io

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`position: absolute;`

will make the sidebar independent of the rest of the page

Comment: That worked! But I never used absolute positioning before, how do position stuff? My sidebar has 2 divs right now, one for Quotes, and one for Category. When I used relative they were placed on top of each other. When I change to absolute they all get jammed together onto one space.

Comment: http://www.barelyfitz.com/screencast/html-training/css/positioning/    try using `position: absolute` only for the div you want to be independent of the rest of your elements.

Comment: The real problem was that it was pushing the main content down. I didn't want the margins and height of my sidebar to affect my main content. What I noticed now that with an absolute position, it also messes up when I zoom out or in. Is there a possible way to keep the relative positioning, but also avoid my sidebar's content to mess up the rest of my site?

Comment: only the actual sidebar wrapper should have `position:absolute`; the rest of the stuff inside it should not; else they too will be independent of the other stuff inside the wrapper

Comment: Oh that fixed it! Can you check it? http://oldtimesdaily.tumblr.com/ your solutions fixed it all. But when I zoom in a lot, the sidebar moves around. Will that be a problem for mobile devices with lower resolutions?

Comment: I'm glad that you made it work using my suggestions; could you please mark this as an answer (the checkbox) if you feel it answered your question? Regarding mobile devices, that is called Responsive CSS https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Responsive_CSS and I'm not sure if using the `position` attribute. is a good technique there.